# Noticeable lag in hotkey, how can i reduce the delay?

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to change the hotkey Win + E to Win + Space and i used the code below

Code:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey 
releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and 
reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

#space:: Run explorer.exe shell:MyComputerFolder
```

which worked fine but i noticed a lag. when i use Win + E its opens instantly but when i use Win + Space there is a 1 sec delay.

Is there anyway to get rid of this delay?

Comment: Can you define both keys in the same script and validate, that win-e is always faster? Because it's more likely to have other causes outside of the hotkey.

Comment: yes, there is a difference with measurements. here is [a script](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=56441) that tells you. See the response by Rohwedder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution on AutoHotKey forums. If anyone is interested here it is

Answered by username: **TheDewd**

> #NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey 
>   releases.
>
> ; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
>
> SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and 
>   reliability.
>
> SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
>
> #space::#e ;this line solves the delay. Makes it Just like using Win + E
>
> #e:: ;if you want to remap Win + E
>
> MsgBox, Test
>
> return

[Reference](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=56441), just incase but all the answer is in the code above.